# Changing the permission so the directory is world writable on CentOS 7

Tags: apache, centos, xenforo

I've installed Xenforo on my digitalocean VPS running CentOS 7, I get this error as soon as I open the web page. `The following errors occurred while verifying that your server can run XenForo:

```
The directory /var/www/html/data must be writable. Please change the permissions on this directory to be world writable (chmod 0777). If the directory does not exist, please create it.
The directory /var/www/html/internal_data must be writable. Please change the permissions on this directory to be world writable (chmod 0777). If the directory does not exist, please create it.
Please correct these errors and try again.
```

How would I change the permission for the directory so it can be world writable?

Comment: World writable is very insecure. But here it goes `chmod 0777 /var/www/html/data /var/www/html/internal_data`. You might want to set sticky bit to make it less insecure. `chmod 1777 /var/www/html/data /var/www/html/internal_data`.

Comment: The errors show you the commands you need but I wouldn't suggest running them. World-writable anything is generally a **horrible** idea.

Comment: If it's very insecure, is there any way around it to continue using Xenforo?

Answer (score 0):

Basically `data` and `internal_data` are directories in which the user running Xenforo should be able to write, because they will contain attachments, avatar, and other files.

Usually the user running PHP on Apache or Nginx is `www-data` in the group `www-data` (user and group have the same name), so all you have to do is letting this user to write on `data` and `internal_data`:

```
chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/html/data /var/www/html/internal_data
```

If you want to follow literally the advice given in the error message you can do this instead:

```
chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/data /var/www/html/internal_data
```

But as others commented, this approach is more insecure, because it will permit **any** user in the system to write in `data` and `internal_data` directories.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is recommended for Xenforo 2 on nginx on CentOS per CentMinMod & Xenforo [documentation](https://centminmod.com/nginx_configure_xenforo_seo_friendly_urls.html).  It is required to do it like this or Xenforo2 will not work.  I have used this on multiple sites without issue.  Make a backup first to be safe.

```
find /home/nginx/domains/domain.com/public/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644;
find /home/nginx/domains/domain.com/public/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755;
find /home/nginx/domains/domain.com/public/internal_data/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0777;
find /home/nginx/domains/domain.com/public/data/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0777;
find /home/nginx/domains/domain.com/public/internal_data/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0777;
find /home/nginx/domains/domain.com/public/data/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0777;
chmod 0750 /home/nginx/domains/domain.com/public;
```